# logback how to log only the classname not also the package path?

Tags: java, logback

I have an appender in my logback xml config:

```
    <encoder>
        <pattern>%d{"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"} [%thread] %-5level %logger{5} - %msg %n</pattern>
    </encoder>
```

but it prints out the abbreviated package along with the class, even if I set it to `%logger{1}` like:

> 2019-12-19 10:26:16 [main] INFO  o.f.d.d.u.Myclass - my message

I want it to just log the class `MyClass` like log4j does.  How?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

looks like the number you specify for `%logger` is some kind of special case and doesnt' exactly dictate size.  Except it does dictate size, but never less than a minimum size which is the entire package path with the full class name.  Unless you set it to "0" which is a special case to mean "don't include the package".

So if I set it to `%logger{0}` then I get just the class name, see http://logback.qos.ch/manual/layouts.html#conversionWord

> 2019-12-19 10:28:45 [main] INFO  MyClass - my message

In log4j the equivalent would have been `%c{1}` or `%logger{1}` so I guess it's different.